# How to scan multi-line input with lex

Tags: string, long-integer, lex

A standard way of saving long lines in a file is to split them into shorter sub-lines and end each sub-line except the last with a backslash character.

I want to create lex/flex rules to scan such lines. How to I tell the scanner to read and concatenate them first and only then try to apply the rules to the "long" string?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question-- are you asking about how to get the scanner to read and concatenate the lex rules you define?? If you're defining lex rules, are you planning to generate a lexer? The lexer would take care of consuming the message using the rules you've defined. Sorry in advance if i've misunderstood your wording!

Answer (score 1):

You'd best redefine the `input` macro to remove any occurrences of backslash-newline from the input stream. So in a sense you put a preprocessor to the tokenizer.